# JPA 2.0 NamedQuery Left Join

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables Departments, Teachers, like below:

```
Departments     Teachers
---             ---   
D_ID            T_ID
Code            Name
                Dept (logically reference D_ID)
```

Due to some old record in Teachers, with contains invalid value of Dept, e.g., A teacher with Dept = 5, but there is no D_ID = 5 in Departments.

In SQL, I could use 
`SELECT t.*, COALESCE(d.Code, t.Dept) as Dept FROM Teachers t LEFT JOIN Departments d ON d.D_ID = t.Dept` to get the expected result, but I am not sure how to do in JPA using LEFT JOIN, and return the result as a Teachers entity.

I had defined both Teachers entity and Departments entity, but due to the old record, I am not sure if I should define `@OneToOne / @OneToMany / @ManyToOne` relation in Teachers or Departments entity.

```
class Teachers
String T_ID;
String Name;
String Dept;
@Transient 
String DeptCode;

class Departments
String D_ID;
String Code;
```

I am a beginner using JPA, and I am using JPA 2.0 with SpringDataJPA and Hibernate.

Please give some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a namedQuery in your repository interface and define a constructor in class Teachers and use it in the query to return the result you want. Suppose that *Teachers* is the package *main.ct* you can do it like this:

```
@Query("SELECT new main.ct.Teachers(t.T_ID, t.Name, t.Dept, COALESCE(d.Code, t.Dept)) FROM Teachers t LEFT JOIN Departments d WHERE d.D_ID = t.Dept")
   List<Teachers> findAllTeachers();
```

And define the constructor:

```
public Teachers(String id, String name, String dept, String deptCode)
{
   this.T_ID = id;
   this.Name = name;
   this.Dept = dept;
   this.DeptCode = deptCode;
}
```

And if you have not define a repository interface for Teachers, do it like this:

```
@Repository
public interface TeachersRepo extends JpaRepository<Teachers, String>{
//write here your query
}
```

Or you can do the same thing in your entity with the annotation *@NamedQuery*
as explained in this link:

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named

Comment: I tried but fail. I got the following exception. Is it version problem? I am using Hibernate 4.2.21  
  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1

Comment: I don't think it's a version problem, try to remove the on condition and put it in the WHERE clause. I edited the answer. In my case it works but i just find out that it's not recommended the use of JOIN ON in hql, like explained in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003430/hibernate-query-syntax-exception-org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexception-u